# Specifically writing from an array of courses to a csv file

Tags: java, arrays, io

I'm having trouble using a method from a class that I have written. The following method was added to a class I created named Course. The goal is to write all of the properties of the object on one line as a String.

```
// method to return properties as a CSV string on one line
public String toCSVString(Course c) {
   String record = c.campus + ","
   + c.course + ","
   + c.section + ","
   + c.crn + ","
   + c.credits + ","
   + c.time + ","
   + c.days + "\n";

   return record;
} //end toCSVString()
```

OK, so after adding that method to the Class. I then began to create a method (which is called from the main method) needed to write from a Course array to a CSV File which calls the above method. This is the method I wrote.

```
// add a method here to write from an array of courses to a CSV file
public static void writeCSV(Course[] courseArray, int count) throws Exception {

   //create a File class object and give the file the name employees.csv
   java.io.File courseCSV = new java.io.File("courses.csv");

   //Create a Printwriter text output stream and link it to the CSV File
   java.io.PrintWriter outfile = new java.io.PrintWriter(courseCSV);

   //Iterate the elements actually being used
   for (int i=0; i < count ; i++) {
      outfile.write(courseArray.toCSVString(courseArray[i]));

   }//end for

   outfile.close();
} //end writeCSV()
```

I'm having trouble with the line that starts with "outfile.write"

In my code, I am having trouble getting Netbeans to locate the toCSVString method which is defined after the toString method in the Course class.  Originally that line in the code looked like this:

```
outfile.write(toCSVString(courseArray[i]));
```

But my IDE could not find it so I added the instance of the course object in front of it. However, I am still having trouble.

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT** #1

Here is the Course class in my program. I am having issues with the toCSVString method.

```
class Course implements Serializable {

   private String campus;  // the campus on which the course is offered
   private String course;  // the course number, such as CSCI 111
   private String section; // the section number
   private String crn;     // the CRN for this section
   private int credits;    // the number od credits for the course
   private String time;    // the time the course is offered, such as 8:00 to 10:00 A.M.
   private String days;    // the Days the course is offered, suhc as MW


   // constructors
Course() {
}

Course(String course, String section, String crn, int credits) {
    this.course = course;
    this.section = section;
    this.crn = crn;
    this.credits = credits;
}   // end Course() initalizing

// muatator methods
public void setCampus(String cmp) {
    this.campus = cmp;
}// end setCampus()

public void setCourse(String crse) {
    this.course = crse;
}// end setCourse()

public void setSection(String sect) {
    this.section = sect;
}   // end setSection()

public void setCRN(String crn) {
    this.crn  = crn;
}   // end setCRN()

public void setCredits(int cr) {
    this.credits = cr;
}   // end setCredits()

public void setTime(String tm) {
    this.time = tm;
}// end setTime()

public void setDays(String days) {
    this.days = days;
}// end setDays()




// accessor methods
public String getCampus() {
    return campus;
}   // end getCampus()

public String getCourse() {
    return course;
}   // end Course()

public String getSection() {
    return section;
}   // end getSection()

public String getCRN() {
    return crn;
}   // end getCRN()

public int getCredits() {
    return credits;
}   // end getCredits()

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}   // end getTime()

public String getDays() {
    return days;
}   // end getDays()


// method to compare by CRN using the String class compareTo()
public int compareTo(Course other) {
    return this.crn.compareTo(other.getCRN());
}   // end compareTO()

// method to return properties as a string
public String toString() {

    return campus + " "
            + course + " "
            + section + " "
            + crn + " "
            + credits + " "
            + time + " "
            + days;

}    // end toString()

// method to return properties as a CSV string on one line
//public String toCSVString(Course c){
public String toCSVString (Course c){
    String record = campus + ","
                  + course + ","
                  + section + ","
                  + crn + ","
                  + credits + ","
                  + time + ","
                  + days + "\n";

    return record;
} //end toCSVString()


}// end class Course
```

Comment: Please show us the entire class (or at least an outline of it). Is `toCSVString()` actually a member of `Course`?

Comment: @JasonC I added the method to Course myself. I am going to update the above question showing the Course class.

Comment: Do you want to print all the `courses` in your `courseArray`? If that so you don't need the `count` variable. Also if you `constructor` is empty you can skip the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
outfile.write(courseArray.toCSVString(courseArray[i]));
```

You mean:

```
outfile.write(courseArray[i].toCSVString(courseArray[i]));
```

As `toCSVString` is a member of `Course`, not of `Course[]` (`courseArray` is a `Course[]` and you are attempting to call `.toCSVString()` on the array itself, which is not valid).

Also note that in this form, it is redundant to pass the `Course` as a parameter, as you are not using it and you also would want `this` instead of some other `Course` anyways. I recommend either ditching that parameter entirely (since it is unused):

```
public String toCSVString () {      // <- c wasn't actually used
    String record = campus + ","    // <- and this. is implied here
                  + course + ","
                  + section + ","
                  + crn + ","
                  + credits + ","
                  + time + ","
                  + days + "\n";
    return record;
}
```

And you simply call it as:

```
outfile.write(courseArray[i].toCSVString());
```

Or, if you prefer you can make the method `static` and use the parameter (although that does not get you any particular benefit in this situation):

```
public static String toCSVString (Course c) {
    String record = c.campus + "," 
                  + c.course + ","
                  + c.section + ","
                  + c.crn + ","
                  + c.credits + ","
                  + c.time + ","
                  + c.days + "\n";
    return record;
}
```

If you choose the static approach then you call it as:

```
outfile.write(Course.toCSVString(courseArray[i]));
```

Comment: That answered my question. Thank you so much for the in-depth response. Can't thank you enough.